# File not found error when copying kubeconfig file to jenkins context

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubeconfig, k0s

I am trying to access a k0s cluster with Jenkins in order to deploy from Jenkins pipeline. In order to copy/paste cluster credentials in the kubeconfig file I tried to access with "~/.kube/config" command but there is an error saying "No such file or directory" i.e when I run :

```
sudo cp ~/.kube/config ~/.jenkins/.kube/
```

I get ***No such file or directory*** error. It appears as if the config file is not there or may be located elsewhere where I am not aware.
I have created a kubeconfig file for the root user (on the assumption that it doesnt exist by default) as per the documentation [here](https://docs.k0sproject.io/main/cli/k0s_kubeconfig_create/) :

```
k0s kubeconfig create root
```

but when I reattempt to copy I am still getting same error 'No such file or directory'. The kubeconfig file *has been created* as per output from this command `k0s kubeconfig create root`  :

```
WARN[2022-01-30 17:44:16] no config file given, using defaults

apiVersion: v1
clusters:

cluster:
server: https://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:6443
certificate-authority-data: xxxxxxxx
name: k0s
contexts:
context:
cluster: k0s
user: root
name: k0s
current-context: k0s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
name: root
user:
client-certificate-data: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I can verify that the file indeed exists with command `k0s kubectl config view`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:

cluster:
certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
server: https://localhost:6443
name: local
contexts:
context:
cluster: local
namespace: default
user: user
name: Default
current-context: Default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
name: user
user:
client-certificate-data: REDACTED
client-key-data: REDACTED
```

One of the posts suggests using the command `k0s kubectl get pods -v=6` to see the exact location of the kubeconfig file but when I run it -v seems unsupported for k0s :

```
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'v' in -v=6
See 'k0s kubectl get --help' for usage
```

As a check I have done `cd ~/.kube/config` but there is nothing also there

What am I missing ?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Bare metal server

Comment: Please answer my other questions, especially what version you used. Additionally, please explain exactly how you created this cluster.

Comment: I followed this guide https://techviewleo.com/deploy-kubernetes-cluster-on-debian-using-k0s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was missing :

~/.kube/config does NOT get created by k0s by default at all. What k0s does create by default is the "break-the-glass" admin kubeconfig which is located at /var/lib/k0s/pki/admin.conf

So I had to do :

1. `cp /var/lib/k0s/pki/admin.conf ~/.kube/config`
2. `cp ~/.kube/config/admin.conf /var/lib/jenkins`
3. Add jenkins user to sudo users :

nano -f /etc/sudoers

then

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The recommended way however is to avail dedicated access for Jenkins with proper RBAC allowing only the needed access e.g service account tokens.  As next step I will have to test this on another Jenkins instance since I can no longer revoke access (disadvantage of using admin.conf)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the kubeconfig to location `/root/.kube/config` by using following command:

```
k0s kubectl config view --raw > ~/.kube/config
```

After creating the file, you should not get the mentioned error `"no such file or directory"`.